# How to use puppet to install and configure custom app?

Tags: puppet

My goal is for my users to start with a base Linux machine, install puppet, clone my GitHub repo and run `puppet apply myapp.pp`, this should then using puppet:

1) configure the system with any pre-requisites etc,
2) git clone another repo that contains my application code
3) compile, install and configure my application.

The specifics of getting Puppet to do 1, 2 and 3 seem fairly straight-forward, but what I cannot understand is if I should write a Puppet Module, or just a Manifest?

I started with a Manifest, but templating did not seem to work, puppet always complained it could not find the .erb files. That work can be seen here: https://github.com/adamretter/exist-puppet.

After making some enquiries, I was told that I needed to refactor my code into a Puppet module, which I have started to do here: https://github.com/adamretter/puppet-exist.

However there seems to be no way to run `puppet apply` on a module, so how do I achieve what I am looking for? Someone said that I need to call my module from a small .pp file stub, but I cannot see how to do that in the same git repo, as when I try to include it, it says it cannot find my module?

Are there any good examples where this is kinda thing is already done?

I have tried to follow the Puppet documentation, but it seems to make leaps or assume too much: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/module_guides/bgtm.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, post your errors when you run a command, that will help debug the problem. Here are a few tips you can follow:

To apply a standalone module, you need to have the following structure :

```
<modulename>/manifests/init.pp
                      /<subname>.pp
```

`init.pp` content may look like this :

```
 class <modulename> {
      notify {"New module using Puppet apply":}
      include <modulename>::<subname>
  }
```

`subname.pp` content may look like this :

```
 class <modulename>::<subname> {
      # Some manifest
 }
```

All these files need to be physically on the client machine in order for `puppet apply` to work. And you need to be in the parent directory of `<modulename>` while running `puppet apply` command. You can do,

```
 puppet apply -e 'include <modulename>'
```

As @FelixFrank suggested, you can give the `modulepath` as an argument.

```
 puppet apply -e 'include <modulename>' --modulepath=/path/to/modules
```

Comment: Very good! Note also that the module must be in the `$modulepath` (or newly, in `modules/` inside the current environment directory). As a simple override, you can use another paramter, `puppet apply -e 'include exist' --modulepath=.` assuming you are in the parent directory.

Comment: @FelixFrank Added your suggestion about modulepath. Thanks.